# Are harmonics going to be introduced if we add capacitor to correct the power factor of a plant?

Tags: capacitor, harmonics

Suppose there are no harmonics in our installation,  will adding capacitors  introduce harmonics to our installation ?

Answer (score 1):

No capacitors do not introduce harmonics.

They may resonate with odd harmonic currents on transformer core.

How many VAR is cap and transformer each?

Do you have Remanence or just getting close to saturation voltage?

Answer (score 0):

In this modern day and age, I seriously doubt that your facility has ZERO harmonics... If you are typing your question on a PC that is connected to this facility, YOU have just introduced harmonics via the power supply of that PC. Maybe not a significant amount, but it IS harmonics. All forms of non-linear loads create harmonics and virtually EVERYTHING electronic will be a non-linear load; PC power supplies, all forms of battery chargers, fluorescent lighting, HID lighting, speed controls for motors, servo amplifiers, UPS systems etc. etc. The only linear loads are resistance heating, incandescent lighting and motors running DOL / Across-the-line. Potentially then, adding PFC capacitors COULD in theory interact with any existing harmonics. But the caps will not CREATE more harmonics, it's far more likely that they will TRAP them and that causes excess heating inside of the caps, shortening their life. How much is totally subjective to the conditions at hand; it may be nothing significant, it may be totally disastrous. I have seen both.